# Trouble doing conditional layout rendering on nextjs13

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

im trying to make a rootLayout on my nextjs 13 app, the thing is that i want to render a sidebar on every page, but not in my auth page (route: /auth)

The thing is that i dont want to make the layout a client component, because that would make all components client components. I have tried a lot of things but no one properly works.

Root layout

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
  session
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  session: Session
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <Providers session={session}>
          <div className='flex w-screen h-screen font-inter light'>
            <Sidebar />
            <AuthCheck />
            <main>{children}</main>
          </div>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple layouts in your project eg

[image: multiple layouts in next js]

Here layout with red underline is for the login page and layout with green underline is the home page with a sidebar inside of it. 
github repo: https://github.com/ng9000/notion-clone